# Apache Nifi, PublishJMS processor fails while publishing json message to IBM Websphere MQ to overwrite JMS_IBM_* properties

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, apache-nifi

with ref to post : [PublishJMS processor fails while publishing json message to IBM Websphere MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245201/publishjms-processor-fails-while-publishing-json-message-to-ibm-websphere-mq) -- it helps.

But i have an another issue while publishing the message to ibm mq queue as is read from another queue. the issue is with JMS_IBM_Encoding value being defaulted to 273 by nifi.

the scenario i was trying to do is, read a msg from one IBM MQ queue and put it on a different queue as is without any modifications using nifi. meaning expecting the same functionality as dump and qload in IBM MQ terms.

Please advise on how to preserve these values as is forwarding with the message.

Comment: This is only a hint for you as I'm not familiar with nifi, or specifically how to implement this with JMS: You would likely need to look into if it is possible and how to get JMS to "save all context" when you get from one queue and "pass all context" when you put to a different queue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion JoshMc. i was using the same mqm user with all privileges to get, set, pass all context. but still some how the nifi specific plugin API is defaulting the value to 273 even though i am forcing it use the value i get from the message. Any idea on how to check env being set while doing a put call from the plugin?

Comment: In the lower level MQI API you can open a queue with the open option `MQOO_SAVE_ALL_CONTEXT` and `MQOO_PASS_ALL_CONTEXT`.  If you open the respective source and destination queues with the above options, then the MQMD is passed to the new queue, this should include the encoding.  If JMS API can do this is a question I don't know the answer to.